# what do * here define for?

Tags: c++, c

```
#define xyz

static xyz  myObject *__my_getitem (myObject* a, myObject *b) {
     myObject *r;
     .........
     ........
     return r;
 }
```

1. What is `static`?
2. What is `xyz` doing with `static`
3. Why is there a `*` in front of `__my_getitem`
4. What is the difference betweern `myObject* a` and `myObject *a` (position of `*`)

Comment: Please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Answers to your questions: learn C++.

Comment: I suggest you pick up a beginners book on C++ (or C), as this is very basic stuff.

Comment: I hope you'll find the answers before the end of your exam ;)

Comment: yes I am new to the C n C++. But want to learn it quickly as I have deadline for the submission :(

Comment: @SumeetShrestha: Good luck with that. I'm still learning after 15 years.

Comment: As much as this question is dying for a good burn ill be the bigger man and just add a link to a nice c tutorial in my opinion : http://www.physics.drexel.edu/courses/Comp_Phys/General/C_basics/

Comment: @Sumeet, [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_e7LB8W_AJh4/S-QBt7K6t8I/AAAAAAAAAFo/F4mXh75R_b4/s1600/Teach-yourself-C++-in-21-days.PNG) is the best way to learn it quickly, as everyone knows.

Comment: @oopsi : that will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Hi, please help me to get rid of the ban from asking the question. I am not able to post any question now as my reputation is very bad.

Comment: your questions suck,  they aren't very good,  thats why you are banned,   try answering a few questions and getting your reputation good again,  that way you  will get the hang of asking better questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is `static`?

It means different things in different contexts; you'll need to read your book to understand all of its meanings. In this case, it means that the function is only available inside this source file, and not in any that are compiled separately and then linked to it.

> What is `xyz` doing with `static`?

Causing confusion. It's an empty macro (defined in the first line) so, before compiling the program, the preprocessor will replace it with nothing.

> Why is there a `*` in front of `__my_getitem`

`*` after a type changes the type to a pointer; so this means that the function returns a pointer to a `myObject`. (By the way, you should never declare a name with two consecutive `_` characters; names like that are reserved.)

> What is the difference betweern `myObject* a` and `myObject *a` (position of *)

Nothing at all; whitespace never changes the meaning of the program, except where it is needed to separate tokens. Some people fight holy wars over the semantic implications of those two styles, but the language doesn't care.

Answer (score 2):

*What is static?*

Function definitions that are prefaced by "static" have their scope limited. They can only be seen and used by functions in the same source file. You would do that when you have a function that has no value outside of the processing taking place in the current file, or you want to limit usage so that it can be modified in the future with less ramifications due to its limited scope.

*What is xyz doing with static*

In this specific case, xyz gets replaced with nothing, so it does nothing. In the general case, it would likely be modifying how the compiler generates this function, changing the "calling convention". That is, xyz would have some meaning to the compiler and is not part of the C language.

*Why is there an asterisk in front of* __my_getitem

It shows that the __my_getitem function returns a pointer to a myObject.

*What is the difference between* myObject* a and myObject *a (position of *)

Nothing, as the syntax is flexible.